# How to write the SQL QUERY for this question

Tags: sql

Given the CITY and COUNTRY tables, query the names of all the continents (COUNTRY.Continent) and their respective average city populations (CITY.Population) rounded down to the nearest integer.

Note: CITY.CountryCode and COUNTRY.Code are matching key columns.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
select 
   c.continent,
   floor(avg(ci.population))
from country c
join city ci
on c.Code = ci.countrycode 
group by 
   c.continent;
```

Comment: This is a working correct answer for mssql.